# Sequence and equation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am having a problem finding an equation for this sequence: 2, 2+4 , 2+4+6, 2+4+6+8 .

Can someone show me the steps in solving this?

Comment: You mean *formula* not equation.

Comment: Do you notice a pattern for how to generate the next term?  $2+4+6+8+10$ would be next, right?  Notice that there is a "+" and 2 more than the last term for how to get the next one.

Answer (score 4):

We have $a_1 = 2 \times 1$, $a_2 = 2 \times 1 + 2 \times 2$, $a_3 = 2 \times 1 + 2 \times 2 + 2 \times 3$.

In general, we have
$$a_n = 2 \times 1 + 2 \times 2 + 2 \times 3 + \cdots + 2 \times n = 2 \times (1+2+\cdots+n) = 2 \times\dfrac{n(n+1)}2 = n(n+1)$$

Comment: I understand it. Thank you guys